# NSFetchedResultsController randomly crashes with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, core-data, crash, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an iOS application which uses Core Data to temporarily store some data downloaded by internet into a database. These data are used to populate an UITableView through a NSFetchedResultsController. Here's the code (placed into the UIViewController) which generates the controller:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

// Fetch results from database
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectContext:[self.appDelegate ordersObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"patronName" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

// Prefetch size: tweak this to improve performance
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self.appDelegate ordersObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"patronNameInitial" cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[entity release];
[sort release];
[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];

return fetchedResultsController;
```

}

In my application work flow, the table view to which this controller is wrapped has to be unloaded and loaded several time, and here comes the problem. Once the context is populated by my "Order" entities, if I switch back and forth to the view with the results controller, after several times of pushes and pops from the view stack the application crashes with the following error:

```
Fatal error. NSInvalidArgumentException. Entity name must not be nil.. User info: (null)
```

The curious thing is that, for a given set of data that the controller has to display, the crash occurs EXACTLY at the same time in every application run. Example: always at the sixth time I display the view with the data.

But how is this possible if my object context does not change in the meanwhile? Why (example) it works 5 times the sixth time I get this error?

Please note that my managed object context and model are owned by my application delegate and never unloads, so the data should not change over time if I don't explicitly modify them.

Maybe the issue is because I don't actually save the "Orders" to the database but I keep them in memory, in the object context? I do this because when the application stops, the downloaded data has to be wiped.

**EDIT 1:** I tried to log right the line before the crash occurs, and

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[self.appDelegate managedObjectModel] entities]);
```

Is causing the application to crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, so the problem occurs in the managedObjectModel.

**EDIT 2:** I tried to fill the context with more than 1500 entities, and I after loading and unloading the view for 30 times I didn't have any crash. It seems I get crashes only when the managed object context contains only few entities! This is so weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be releasing entity

```
[entity release];
```

Since you never called alloc on it, you don't own it.

Comment: Hi Sherman, thanks for your answer. You surely pointed out a mistake of mine. I'll try right now to delete this line, not releasing the entity and see if something changes. But, if you are right, why the exception is not thrown the first time I release the entity? Something happens after 4 times, something after 6, something it doesn't seem to happen (depending on the fetched data)! It's the apparently random pattern that scares me.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. Maybe I should read and study more about memory management. That'll be my homework for tomorrow. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are not caching section informations. Why not ? Set `cacheName:@"Root"` to use the advantage of the `NSFetchResultController`.
Note that this only makes sense if the settings of the `FetchRequestController` are immutable. As far as I can see in your posted code, that's what you have here. So you should go ahead and cache your section informations. Your data will only be loaded into the cache on first launch with a little bit of overhead but later on only observes changes in your table view.

I am trying to think if that could also be a reason for your problem but only have vague assumptions I am not sure about, so I will leave them out here. But try changing that...

Comment: Hi brainttf! Thanks for you answer. I'm not caching the result because the ViewController is also an UISearchBarDelegate, and the fetch request predicate changes everytime the search string changes. I don't think it would be a good idea to delete and recache every time! Am I wrong? I'm a complete newbie, so I'm open to every suggestion!

Comment: @Andrea: No, in that case you are right. However what you could do is use two different `UIFetchResultControllers`: one to cache all entries and one without caching for all the other search cases. Anyway that doesn't answer your question...

Comment: Yes, I did read a post here on Stackoverflow on how to do that, it will surely be an optimization of my app. For now I'm trying to focus my priorities on resolving these issues, then I will optimize what I can. Thanks for your suggestion!